# Record python version to rebuild virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

The convention to record package requirements for future installation in a python virtual environment is to use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then install using `pip install -r requirements.txt`

The python interpreter version, however, is not recorded in the requirements.txt file.

Is there a similar convention to record the python version so that the entire virtual env, including the python interpreter used, can be easily rebuilt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pipenv` for virtualenv creation and package management needs, e.g.:

```
pipenv --python 3.6
pipenv --python 3
```

See the documentation:
https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/basics/#specifying-versions-of-python

That way, when you'll recreate the env with `pipenv`, it'll use the specified Python version and install the required packages.

Comment: What if I do not want to create another venv

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. 

To create another venv, use pipenv to create your new env (just like you would with virtualenv, it's a wrapper around it).

Comment: I don’t want to create another venv. I already have one. I just want to use Pipenv in an existing venv.

Comment: You don't need to, `pipenv` respects existing, activated, virtualenvs.

Answer (score 0):

Such requirements cannot be written in `requirements.txt` or `setup.py`: when one runs

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`pip` is already being run with some version of Python.

Python version requirement could be implemented in a script that creates and populates a virtual env.

But best of all it must be written in the docs!